# link incorrectly to a figure

Tags: hyperref

Let me describe. I have a document with figures and I refer to them correctly by using `\label` and `\ref`. 
Now I add an appendix and reset numbering for figures in the appendix with

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
```

And here is an example of figures in the appendix

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{abc.png}
\caption{Example.}
\label{FigA1}
\end{figure}
```

In the text I refer to figures in the appendix, for example:
 `Figure \ref{FigA1} on page \pageref{FigA1}...`
And in the compiled file, it shows
 `Figure A1 on page 7...`
It seems everything is ok. However when I click on the "A1" in the compiled text to go to the figure A1, it goes to the figure 1 in the main text, even it shows correctly page 7 of figure A1.

This problem is so strange and could you help me to solve it. thanks a lot.

---

here is the preamble part

```
\documentclass[reprint,
superscriptaddress,
amsmath,amssymb,
 aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{hblue}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) A sniplet preamble like this does not help us much in helping you. Please provide a minimal fully compilable example (preferably with the figures replaceed by say `\rule{4cm}{4cm}` (as we don't have your figures). That makes it much more likely that others can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix the issue by also modifying the definition of `\theHfigure`, which `hyperref` uses for creating links.

```
\documentclass[
  reprint,
  superscriptaddress,
  amsmath,amssymb,
  aps
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

Some text with a reference to the first figure in
the main body (see figure~\ref{FigMain}) and a
reference to the figure in the appendix (see figure~\ref{FigApp}).

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{Main figure}
\label{FigMain}
\end{figure}

Some other text.

\clearpage

\appendix

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

Some text in the appendix

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Appendix figure}
\label{FigApp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```