# How to keep figure index number/style and \hyperref after included into another tex?

Tags: hyperref, include, standalone

The document(supp.tex) to be included into another (main.tex) has a indexing style that start with "S":

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
```

How to keep this naming style after included to the main tex?

It is included with `standalone` package, MWE of main tex:

```
\documentclass[review, authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \include{supp}
\end{document}
```

(For example, fig 1, 2, 3 in main.tex; fig S1, S2, S3 in supp.tex. After include supp.tex into main.tex, the figures will become fig 4, 5, 6, but I want to keep these figures named as fig S1, S2, S3.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new counter to store the old value of the counter `figure` before including `supp.tex`, and restoring it to its previous value and style after exiting the include:

File `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[review, authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{img1.jpeg}
        \caption{test}
        \label{fig:fig_1}
    \end{figure}

    Here, a test \hyperref[fig:fig_1]{Figure 1}, and a test for \hyperref[fig:fig_s1]{Figure S1}, and a test for \hyperref[fig:fig_2]{Figure 2}.

    \newcounter{tmpfigure}
    \setcounter{tmpfigure}{\value{figure}}
    \input{supp}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
    \setcounter{figure}{\value{tmpfigure}}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{img1.jpeg}
        \caption{test}
        \label{fig:fig_2}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

File `supp.tex`:

```
\documentclass[review, authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

    % add "S" before figure index and let hyperref recognize
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\theHfigure}{S\arabic{figure}} 

    % index figure from 1
    \setcounter{figure}{0}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{figure/fmri}
        \caption{For example}
        \label{fig:fig_s1}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

Notice that I replaced `\include` by `\input` (and added `[h]` to environment `figure`) to avoid pagebreaks.

Comment: But there is a problem, the \ref in text seems messed now. I ref with `\hyperref[fig:fig_s1]{Figure S1}`, but it jump to fig 1. The position of this \ref is behind fig 1, before fig S1.

Comment: Don't! Use `\label{myfigure}` in the caption of your figure, and refer to it using `\ref{myfigure}`, see my edited edit.

Comment: It seems non of the matter of ref or hyperref, and non of a matter where label located, when you click the "S1" link, it will jump to fig 1, not fig S1.

Comment: This is the answer for keeping correct ref link, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245097/181532